# get number with specific digit with out press on "enter" key

Tags: c

```
int getGuess()
{
    int number = 0;
    int  i = 0;
    printf("Enter your guess\n");
    for (i = 1; i<=FOUR;i++)
    {
        number = number*TEN + getche();
    }   
    printf("\n");
    return number;
}
```

I did this code, I know that this is a function but in the function that I called to this function I print the value, and it does not work as I expected.
I this is what I enter 2431 and this the real value 55759.
well how could I can get integer number and without press on enter?

Comment: In MSVC you can do that with `_getch()` and there are ways in Linux too.

Comment: I need in C language

Comment: "MSVC" - Microsoft Visual C. Standard C does not have a function that will enter a character without pressing Enter. You need a language extension, which will be specific to the OS.

Comment: Hoooo Tnx I think I got you, I will try you idea... :)

Comment: Please see this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed)

Comment: Your question would be actually better if you added your example as text instead of as an image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed)

Comment: `getch` returns the ASCII value for the digit, you must convert that to the decimal value by subtracting `'0'`, e.g. `number = number*TEN + getche() - '0';` See [ASCII Description](http://asciitable.com)

Comment: Tnx, I will try

Comment: thank you very much, I succeed:)

Answer (score 0):

When you ask for input, the program stops. The system needs to know when the input stops and this is usually the enter key. When the input is provided, the program starts again. This is the default C behaviour. Professional developers write their own input driver to control this start/stop situation.